# Checking if an object is a number

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, types, xml-serialization

I'd like to check if an object is a number so that `.ToString()` would result in a string containing digits and `+`, `-`, `.`

Is it possible by simple type checking in .NET? Like:

```
if (p is Number)
```

Or should I convert to `string`, then try parsing to `double`?

**Update:** To clarify my object is `int`, `uint`, `float`, `double`, and so on, it isn't a `string`.
I'm trying to make a function that would serialize any object to XML like this:

```
<string>content</string>
```

or

```
<numeric>123.3</numeric>
```

or raise an exception.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to write your own XmlSerializer- what is wrong with the one provider by .NET- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx ?

Comment: You might be able to get around this whole problem by defining your XML format using an XSD, and then creating an object into which you can serialize your data using the XSD tool shipped - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @RichardOD: Can I use xml serialization to serialize object[] ? I need it to call Flash function https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=19_External_Interface_178_3.html#126216

Answer (score 211, accepted):

You will simply need to do a type check for each of the basic numeric types.

Here's an extension method that should do the job:

```
public static bool IsNumber(this object value)
{
    return value is sbyte
            || value is byte
            || value is short
            || value is ushort
            || value is int
            || value is uint
            || value is long
            || value is ulong
            || value is float
            || value is double
            || value is decimal;
}
```

This should cover all numeric types.

### Update

It seems you do actually want to parse the number from a string during deserialisation. In this case, it would probably just be best to use `double.TryParse`.

```
string value = "123.3";
double num;
if (!double.TryParse(value, out num))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Value is not a number.");
```

Of course, this wouldn't handle very large integers/long decimals, but if that is the case you just need to add additional calls to `long.TryParse` / `decimal.TryParse` / whatever else.

Comment: My object is int, short, uint, float, double or anything else that is a number

Comment: @Piotr: Ah right. It seems I misunderstood you. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Noldorin: actually your previous version of the code would work as well; just add a null check and use value.ToString(). Then you don't need to check for all the numeric types.

Comment: @Fredrik: That's true. I guess... It may be marginally shorter to read, but I think you'll agree it's a bit of a hack. It certainly is much less efficient.

Comment: @Noldorin It is sad that it the right solution is that verbose :(.

Comment: @Piotr: You could say that... although once it's implemented as an extension method, it's very easy to use. :) I think it's the nature of a static language that means checks have to be performed this way.

Comment: The double.TryParse sample should be using an invariant culture.

Comment: @Joe: Actually, it wouldn't make a difference, since ToString would also use the current culture.

Comment: Like it thanks +1, but I still prefer the Java implementation which all numbers implement a Number interface.

Comment: Needs an update to reflect new types - `System.Half` - `System.Int128` - `System.UInt128` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.half?view=net-7.0 |  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0 | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128?view=net-7.0 )

Answer (score 39):

Taken from [Scott Hanselman's Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringIsNumericForC.aspx):

```
public static bool IsNumeric(object expression)
{
    if (expression == null)
    return false;

    double number;
    return Double.TryParse( Convert.ToString( expression
                                            , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                          , System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any
                          , NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo
                          , out number);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you pass in a string which looks like a number it will format it. Might be ok for most people but it was a show stopper for me.

Comment: Another potential problem with this is that you cannot parse the min/max values for double. `double.Parse(double.MaxValue.ToString())` causes an `OverflowException`. You could remedy this by providing the roundtrip modifier `.ToString("R")` in this case, but that overload isn't available for `Convert.ToString(...)` as we don't know the type. I know this is a bit of a fringe case, but I stumbled into it while writing tests for my own `.IsNumeric()` extension. My "solution" was to add a type checking swtich before trying to parse anything, see my answer to this question for the code.

Answer (score 22):

Take advantage of the IsPrimitive property to make a handy extension method:

```
public static bool IsNumber(this object obj)
{
    if (Equals(obj, null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    objType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objType) ?? objType;

    if (objType.IsPrimitive)
    {
        return objType != typeof(bool) && 
            objType != typeof(char) && 
            objType != typeof(IntPtr) && 
            objType != typeof(UIntPtr);
    }

    return objType == typeof(decimal);
}
```

EDIT: Fixed as per comments.
The generics were removed since .GetType() boxes value types. Also included fix for nullable values.

Comment: The generics part isn't giving you any extra here, is it? you only access GetType() which is available on object...

Comment: It saves one box operation if being called on a value type. Think reusability.

Comment: Why not use typeof(T) instead of obj.GetType, that way you won't get a NullReferenceException if someone passes a null reference type. You could also put a generic constrain on T to accept only value types. Of course you start having a lot of information at compile time if you do that.

Comment: `object` and `string` are not primitive types.

Comment: @jnylen: this answer was quite some time ago. I believe I dug somethin up from reflectorized framework source at the time, but who can tell today... Fixed answer.

Comment: Necromancer Here: FYI, no need to check for `Decimal`, as the primitive form is `Double` and `Short` as per: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive(v=vs.110).aspx).  Otherwise +1, helped me build an ObjectExtension method instead of one for each type.

Comment: 1000M.IsNumber() is False

Comment: decimal is not a primitive. Another unintuitive false   ((object)5).IsNumber()

Answer (score 11):

There are some great answers above. Here is an all-in-one solution. Three overloads for different circumstances.

```
// Extension method, call for any object, eg "if (x.IsNumeric())..."
public static bool IsNumeric(this object x) { return (x==null ? false : IsNumeric(x.GetType())); }

// Method where you know the type of the object
public static bool IsNumeric(Type type) { return IsNumeric(type, Type.GetTypeCode(type)); }

// Method where you know the type and the type code of the object
public static bool IsNumeric(Type type, TypeCode typeCode) { return (typeCode == TypeCode.Decimal || (type.IsPrimitive && typeCode != TypeCode.Object && typeCode != TypeCode.Boolean && typeCode != TypeCode.Char)); }
```

Comment: consider adding null check

Comment: Don't really need null check - as an extension method, you couldn't call it with a null value. Of course somebody could still call as a normal function but that is not the expected usage of an extension method.

Comment: I think one can call it with null value. object obj = null; obj.IsNumeric();

Comment: Thanks Weiro, have fixed it. Didn't realize calling extension method with a null value was possible but of course it is!

Comment: I think the first overload is missing a parenthesis at the end: "return (x==null ? false : IsNumeric(x.GetType())); "

Comment: I think its a little risky in the 3rd function to assume that if the object is not one of those things, then therefore it is numeric. What if some future .NET includes new non-numeric primitives... this could yield a false positive.  Compare to the builtin VB.NET IsNumeric which inverts the logic (more or less) https://stackoverflow.com/a/74044011/3195477

Answer (score 11):

Rather than rolling your own, the most reliable way to tell if an in-built type is numeric is probably to reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and call `Information.IsNumeric(object value)`. The implementation handles a number of subtle cases such as `char[]` and HEX and OCT strings.

Comment: This should be at the top!

Comment: It would be good if it works. In my .net framework 4.7.2 it fails to parse UInt16, whereas help says that it should. Checked disassembly of Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll - if input is a string then it tries to convert it to double, otherwise it calls IsOldNumericTypeCode and checks by Int16 and some others but UInt16 and other unsigned types are ignored

Comment: So the most reliable way is to call VisualBasic?

Comment: @E.vanPutten I wouldn't be using this today.

Answer (score 6):

You could use code like this:

```
if (n is IConvertible)
  return ((IConvertible) n).ToDouble(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
else
  // Cannot be converted.
```

If your object is an `Int32`, `Single`, `Double` etc. it will perform the conversion. Also, a string implements `IConvertible` but if the string isn't convertible to a double then a `FormatException` will be thrown.

Comment: Actually strings will be parsed, but if not in correct format, FormatException is thrown.

Comment: @alfoks: You are absolutely right so I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your input is a string...

There are 2 ways:

use Double.TryParse()

```
double temp;
bool isNumber = Double.TryParse(input, out temp);
```

use Regex

```
 bool isNumber = Regex.IsMatch(input,@"-?\d+(\.\d+)?");
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three different concepts there:

- to check if it **is** a number (i.e. a (typically boxed) numeric value itself), check the type with `is` - for example `if(obj is int) {...}`
- to check if a string could be parsed as a number; use `TryParse()`
- but if the object isn't a number or a string, but you suspect `ToString()` might give something that *looks* like a number, then **call** `ToString()` and treat it as a string

In both the first two cases, you'll probably have to handle separately each numeric type you want to support (`double`/`decimal`/`int`) - each have different ranges and accuracy, for example.

You could also look at regex for a quick rough check.

Answer (score 4):

While writing my own `object.IsNumeric()` extension method based on Saul Dolgin's answer to this question I ran into a potential issue in that you will get an `OverflowException` if you try it with `double.MaxValue` or `double.MinValue`.

My "solution" was to combine the accepted answer from Noldorin with the one from Saul Dolgin and add a pattern matching switch before trying to parse anything (and use some C#7 goodness to tidy up a bit):

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return false;

    switch (obj)
    {
        case sbyte _: return true;
        case byte _: return true;
        case short _: return true;
        case ushort _: return true;
        case int _: return true;
        case uint _: return true;
        case long _: return true;
        case ulong _: return true;
        case float _: return true;
        case double _: return true;
        case decimal _: return true;
    }

    string s = Convert.ToString(obj, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out double _);
}
```

Comment: Beware of nullable types.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 7 a new API was introduced to support [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math), which offers lots of interfaces that are implemented in all numerical types. There is an interface `INumber<TSelf>` which can be used as type constraint for generic methods to only allow for numeric types (`int`, `double`, `decimal`, ...):

```
public void FooBar<T>(T number) where T : INumber<T>
{
   // ...number is a numeric type.
}
```

There are also more fine-grained interfaces for categories of numeric types:

- `IBinaryInteger<T>` for `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, ...
- `IFloatingPoint<T>` for `float`, `double`,  `decimal`, ...
- ...

This way, you can define one or more generic type constraints specifically tailored to the numeric types that you expect to handle in your methods along with the benefits of type safety. This should be your preferred route to take and should save you from expensive or faulty checks and passing `object` around.

---

If you must rely on `object`, you can at least use the new `INumber<T>` interface to check with reflection if it is a numeric type. You would check if the type implements any concrete `INumber<T>` interface, by comparing their generic type definitions to the open generic `INumber<>` type. Please be aware that reflection may incur performance costs that must be considered.

```
private bool IsNumericType(object obj)
{
   return obj
      .GetType()
      .GetInterfaces()
      .Any(@interface => @interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(INumber<>));
}
```

---

The API might provide other useful interfaces for your purpose, like for [formatting and parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math#parsing-and-formatting-interfaces).

Comment: I ended up creating an extension method like so: `public static bool IsNumber(this Type type) => Array.Exists(type.GetInterfaces(), i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(INumber<>));`

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is really

> .ToString() would result in a string
>   containing digits and +,-,.

and you want to use double.TryParse then you need to use the overload that takes a NumberStyles parameter, and make sure you are using the invariant culture.

For example for a number which may have a leading sign, no leading or trailing whitespace, no thousands separator and a period decimal separator, use:

```
NumberStyles style = 
   NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | 
   NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | 
double.TryParse(input, style, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an even shorter version of @Noldorin's excellent answer:

```csharp
public static Boolean IsNumeric(this Object obj) =>
  obj is SByte or Byte or Int16 or UInt16 or Int32 or UInt32 or Int64 or UInt64 or Single or Double or Decimal;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't overlook that .NET includes [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isnumeric) which can be used from C# just as well as VB.** This may be preferable to writing your own, or at least use it as a basis.

---

The way it works is to first look for certain types that can be "converted" to or parsed as numbers (strings, chars, or char arrays), and then finally just checks the type code to see if it is one of the intrinsic numeric types.

If you want to exclude strings or chars then you could use it like so:

```
if (foo.GetType().IsValueType && !(foo is char) && Information.IsNumeric(foo))
{
    // Numeric...
}
```

---

[Reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Information.cs,13) does not seem to include this, but it can be viewed in Visual Studio:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(object Expression)
{
    IConvertible convertible = Expression as IConvertible;
    if (convertible == null)
    {
        char[] array = Expression as char[];
        if (array == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Expression = new string(array);
    }

    TypeCode typeCode = convertible.GetTypeCode();
    if (typeCode == TypeCode.String || typeCode == TypeCode.Char)
    {
        string value = convertible.ToString(null);
        try
        {
            long i64Value = default(long);
            if (Utils.IsHexOrOctValue(value, ref i64Value))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (StackOverflowException ex) { throw ex; }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException ex2) { throw ex2; }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex3) { throw ex3; }
        catch (Exception) { return false; }

        double Result = default(double);
        return DoubleType.TryParse(value, ref Result);
    }

    return IsOldNumericTypeCode(typeCode);
}
```

They way it checks for explicit numeric types is similar to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18857243/3195477 although its logic is inverted in a way which may be more robust/safe: it only returns `true` for a known numeric type, as opposed to returning `false` for known non-numeric types; the latter could lead to a bug if ever other types are added.

```
internal static bool IsOldNumericTypeCode(TypeCode TypCode)
{
    switch (TypCode)
    {
        case TypeCode.Boolean:
        case TypeCode.Byte:
        case TypeCode.Int16:
        case TypeCode.Int32:
        case TypeCode.Int64:
        case TypeCode.Single:
        case TypeCode.Double:
        case TypeCode.Decimal:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this works:

```
object x = 1;
Assert.That(x is int);
```

For a floating point number you would have to test using the float type:

```
object x = 1f;
Assert.That(x is float);
```

Comment: This will work if the object was an int before being implicitly or explicitly cast to an object.  In your example, the magic number 1 is an int, and is then implicity cast into the type of the variable x..  If you'd done object x = 1.0, your assert would have returned false.

Comment: There are numbers that are not ints.

Comment: yes, so my point is basically what @Noldorin have in his answer right now.