# Convert object to number type and check value

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm writing a [pluralization](http://unicode.org/cldr/charts/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) framework using .NET for Windows Store apps. For a custom formatter `string Format(string format, params object[] args)`, I have the following code:

```
public static bool IsExactlyOne(object n)
{
    if (n is Int16)
    {
        return (Int16)n == 1;
    }
    if (n is int) // Int32
    {
        return (int)n == 1;
    }
    if (n is long) // Int64
    {
        return (long)n == 1L;
    }
    if (n is UInt16)
    {
        return (UInt16)n == 1U;
    }
    if (n is uint) // UInt32
    {
        return (uint)n == 1U;
    }
    if (n is ulong) // UInt64
    {
        return (ulong)n == 1UL;
    }
    if (n is byte)
    {
        return (byte)n == 1;
    }
    if (n is sbyte)
    {
        return (sbyte)n == 1;
    }
    if (n is float)
    {
        return (float)n == 1.0F;
    }
    if (n is double)
    {
        return (double)n == 1.0D;
    }
    if (n is decimal)
    {
        return (decimal)n == 1.0M;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported type");
}
```

As you see, it's pretty verbose. Is there some way to simplify this? Please note: `IConvertible` is **not** available for Windows Store apps.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `object` at all? I'd use `ulong` or `double` instead, because implicit conversion should do the rest? And I wouldn't expect a string, list or something else being passed.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have a choice (IValueConverter for example)

Comment: @Mario: It's `object`, because this function is part of a custom formatter following the .NET style `Format(string format, params object[] args)`

Comment: I think you're best off leaving it as is.  There are too many corner cases to check if you try anything shorter than that.

Comment: @Sebastian Negraszus: Have you tried the code in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Dictionary to avoid `if`:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, bool>>()
                    {
                        {typeof(Int16), a => (Int16)a == 1},
                        {typeof(int), a => (int)a == 1},
                         ....
                    };

return dic[n.GetType()](n);
```

Or use `dynamic`:

```
public static bool IsExactlyOne(dynamic n)
{
    return n == 1;
}
```

Comment: The dynamic solution is a good one. The dictionary one is really bad and unnecessary for such a mundane requirement...

Comment: The `dynamic` solution look promissing. I have never use dynamic before. Are there any corner cases where your code will behave differently than mine?

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine:

```
    bool IsExactlyOne(object n)
    {
        int i;
        int.TryParse(n.ToString(), out i);
        return i == 1;
    }
```

Unless when dealing with high precision numbers like 1.000000000000001 which is a problem that already exists in the OP's version.

**The only way to deal with high precision is using decimal explicitly.**

Comment: for added error handling you could return result of the tryparse if false ;)

Comment: This won't work for a double of value 1.0000000000000001 because the `ToString` only prints out the first 15 digits.

Comment: @juharr ok but is 1.0000000000000001 really different from 1?

Comment: @AndersonSilva Yes, it is.  In the OP's current code that would return false, but in your's will return true.

Comment: @juharr the OP's current code has the same problem. It also returns true in this case. The problem is when the value gets boxed into object is also gets rounded.

Comment: wouldn't double.TryParse solve juharrs comment? (Looks like an interesting solution hence my interest)

Comment: @Sayse nope, the value gets rounded before it. When it becomes an object. Same problem as the OP's version.

Comment: Just ran both with `double d = 0.9999999999999996D;` and got different results.  Also I put one too many zeros in there.  It should have been 1.000000000000001, the one in the 15th place.  If you using `ToString("r")` it will work for those, but not sure how it might effect other types.

Comment: `ToString("r")` throws an exception for decimal, so to use that you'd have to also catch the format exception.

Answer (score -1):

There you go:

```
public static bool IsExactlyOne(object n)
{
bool result = false;
try
{
result = Convert.ToDouble(n) == 1.0;
}
catch
{
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for doubles because they get rounded.  The OP's code is checking for exactly one, not is it one if I convert it to `int`.

Comment: Cool. Changed it to ToDouble()

Comment: There are decimal values that `ToDouble` doesn't work for like `0.99999999999999999999999999M`.  Maybe `ToDecimal` would work across the board.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130698/checking-if-an-object-is-a-number-in-c-sharp).

```
string value = "123.3";
double num;
if (!double.TryParse(value, out num))
  throw new InvalidOperationException("Value is not a number.");
```