# Is there a C# equivalent to Java's Number class?

Tags: c#, numbers

I'm new to C#, coming from Java, and I'd like to check whether a certain object is a Number (it can be an Integer, Double, Float, etc).  In Java I did this by saying `if (toRet instanceof Number)`.  I'm hoping there's a similar C# thing like `if (toRet is Number)` but thus far I haven't been able to find a Number class that does this.  Is there a way to do this, or do I have to manually check for Integer, Double, etc?

Edit for more info: Basically what I want to do is eventually have a byte array.  However, when the array is stored in a text file, the parser I'm using can sometimes think it's an integer array or a double array.  In Java, I had this:

```
JSONArray dblist = (JSONArray)result_;
byte[] reallyToRet = new byte[dblist.size()];
Object toComp = dblist.get(0);

if (toComp instanceof Number)
    for (int i=0; i < dblist.size(); ++i) {
        byte elem = ((Number) dblist.get(i)).byteValue();
        reallyToRet[i] = elem;
    }

    return reallyToRet;
}
```

The important bit here is the if statement.  Sometimes the objects in `dblist` would parse as integers, sometimes as doubles, and only rarely as bytes, but all I really care about at the end is the byte value.

Comment: There's not a _direct_ equivalent, but it's certainly not hard to do. Context matters, though, for which solution is best. Can you post some code?

Comment: Looks like the commonly used solution is to create your own check. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130698/checking-if-an-object-is-a-number-in-c-sharp

Comment: There is no need for such a thing in C#, because C# is a strongly typed language, where untyped things (such as having a method with a parameter of type `object`) is not really a good idea to begin with. Post the relevant contextual code where you need such a thing.

Comment: @HighCore: Java is also strongly typed. But in java there's a class `Number` and even classes like `Byte` , `Double`, `Integer`,  or `Short` inherit from it.

Comment: @firechant `the parser I'm using can sometimes think it's an integer array or a double array` - Use `File.ReadAllText()` or something and parse the values yourself. You don't need such a thing in .NET. Also, post a sample piece of data (the text file) that you need to read. There's no need for such a `parser` or whatever in C#.

Comment: Consider `is IConvertible`, an interface implemented by all value type types you'd be interested in.  Which you'll need anyway to actually obtain the value.

Answer (score 10):

Well, yeah, but it's an extension method that just ORs all the possibilities.

This is it:

```
public static bool IsNumber(this object value)
{
    return value is sbyte
            || value is byte
            || value is short
            || value is ushort
            || value is int
            || value is uint
            || value is long
            || value is ulong
            || value is float
            || value is double
            || value is decimal
            || value is BigInteger;
}
```

and you would use it like this:

```
if (toRet.IsNumber());
```

This needs to be in a `static class`.

Comment: It's important to mention this code must live inside a `static class`, otherwise it will not compile. The OP might have no idea what `Extension Methods` are because there is no such thing in java.

Comment: @HighCore It might be good for OP to know how powerful C# is!

Comment: To reduce the field of possibilities I'd contraint the type of value to IComparable instead of object since all of those types implement IComparable.

Comment: @digEmAll It's passed as an `object` so you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about any class for that. But you can check for instance, for integer see

```
int val;
if(Int32.TryParse(integer, out val))  

else
```

Unlikely, you can use Double.TryParse(number, out val) etc.