# How to check if an object is numeric in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check if an object is a number or not.

The **IsNumeric** function below works most of the time except when I pass a value of *"NaN"*

So I have this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object obj = "NaN";

        bool check = IsNumeric(obj);

        if (check)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString() + " is a number");
        }


    }

    public bool IsNumeric(object Expression)
    {
        bool isNum;
        double retNum;
        isNum = Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Expression), out retNum);
        return isNum;
    }
```

But the **IsNumeric** funciton returns *"true"* which is a lie.

I found the suggestion of the **IsNumeric** function here:
[How do I identify if a string is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number)

How can I check if an object is numeric or not?

Comment: are you familiar with `TypeOf` of `GetType()`

Comment: Is Byte[] numeric or not ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx `Object.GetType()` it is a thing in C#

Comment: @MethodMan I guess he wants to check string values.

Comment: if he wanted to check string value then why is there a `IsNumeric` wow @NadiaChibrikova can you elaborate

Comment: Do you expect "NaN" _not_ to be recognized as a number? You could easily exclude that using an `if()` statement.

Comment: @Pabinator, I'm confused as to whether you have an object of unknown type that you want to check (as your description suggests), or if you have a string value that you want to check (as your code suggests).

Comment: @MethodMan well a string can contain a word or a number...

Comment: `object obj = "NaN";`
 `var typeObj = obj.GetType();`

Comment: @Pabinator what are you actually trying to check? :)

Comment: There are some great solutions to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130698/checking-if-an-object-is-a-number-in-c-sharp

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova try my example and put "123" it will still be a type of System.String vs 123 will be of type System.Int32

Comment: @MethodMan I know that, but I think he wants to consider "123" as numeric

Comment: doesn't matter - the code speaks for it's self.. and if `IsNumeric Function is used properly it wouldn't be an issue either..

Comment: other examples as well can be found here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130698/checking-if-an-object-is-a-number-in-c-sharp

Comment: also why not use the var as a string instead of `object` and it will be much easier to accurately determine if the string is a string or integer I will post an even simpler method..

Comment: Are any of these numbers: "seven", "pi", "XLII", "0xDeadBeef", "GDP of the UK in 1993", "sqrt(-1)", "i", "e", "6.02e23", "2^128", "1 megaton TNT in grams of mass defect", "answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything"? Perhaps there's a [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) API that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only trouble is with "NaN" then try this: `isNum = Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Expression), out retNum) && !Double.IsNaN(retNum);`

Btw "Infinity" and "-Infinity" also will be numeric.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind adding a reference to the VB library you can use:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(expression)
```